Need help on GoogleSheets importXML function
I tried to acquire a table content by following function but it did not work. The error message showed "parsing content empty."
=IMPORTXML("https://www.settrade.com/th/equities/quote/LH/analyst-consensus","//*[@id='tableAnalystConcensus']")

How to solve it?
